# Git commit id lost

Tags: git

We have configured one git repository, this repository contains more branches. Recently we faced one issue, we lost a few commits which are pushed from user clone from the repository.

If I run "git log commitid" I can able to see the commit id information, but git branch --contains commitid" doesn't show the branch it belongs to .

Also If I run describe it results below, I ran fsck all options, but looks liet these commits are not tangling commits. Please share your thoughts, why this commits are missing and not attached with any branch.

```
git describe commitid --all 
changes/01/21112/1
```

---

I ran git reflog , but it doesn't show that commit id , we actually cherry-picked the commit from one commit, now I can see the actual commitid (even this commit also not belongs to any commit) and cherry-picked commit id corresponding to actual commit id is missing, I am not able to trace out the cherry-picked commit id

How can I find the lost cherry-picked commit id ?

Comment: Wait, I don't get the second part of your post. Once you cherry-pick the commit you are targetting into a branch, when you run `git log` in the branch you should see a new commit Id with the targetted one in the comments, I think. Is it what happens? and in this case, what are you looking for?

Comment: If it's a cherry-pick, and it's not on the branch that should have received the commit, why not just cherry-pick again?

Comment: Hi Vince, christoper, the commit id which I am looking for the one is cherry-picked commit id, Now I am not able to see the cherry-picked commit id in the bare repository. "git log commitid" I mentioned which is the actual commit id in my local clone , but the cherry-picked commit id from my commit in the remote bare is not found, I can able to cherry-pick from my local commit , but the issue is , we are seeing these kind of cherry-picked commit missing in bare always, hence we like to found the reason for misssing the cherry-picked commit id.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try `git reflog`?

When a commit is unreferenced, for example, with `git reset`, it is actually kept in the repository for some time and even `git gc` won't collect it. That's because they are kept referenced in the **reflog**.

You can see if this is the case with:

```
$ git fsck --no-reflogs
```

The reflog is here to protect you. It allows you to roll back a disastrous `reset`, `rebase`,  or any other command that changes history.

If you want to recover these lost commits, you can get them from the reflog easyly enough.

If you want to delete them for good, you can use something like:

```
$ git reflog expire --all
```

But beware! That may not be undone.

Comment: I ran git reflog , but it doesn't show that commit id , we actually cherry-picked the commit from one commit, now I can see the actual commitid (even this commitid also not belongs to any branch) and cherry-picked commit id corresponding to actual commit id is missing, I am not able to trace out the cherry-picked commit id

How can I find the lost cherry-picked commit id ?

Thanks in Advance